# Scaling a CSS frame-by-frame animation (Save me!)

Tags: html, css, web

I was wondering if one of you could assist me with a CSS/HTML issue I am having.

I have a CSS based animation using the background and the steps() method. Unfortunately, this has meant scaling has been an issue.

Is there a way of simply scaling the div containing this to fit the screen? I don't mind the aspect ratio, that's not an issue. Here is my CSS for the animation:

```
    .pageOpen {
  width: 710.956522px;
  height: 400px;
  background: url('/Images/SiteVitalImages/preloader-open.png') left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: play 1s steps(22) infinite;
}

@keyframes play {
    100% { background-position: right ; }
}
```

I would really appreciate the assistance, this has been quite irritating.

Here is a gif of the issue:
https://gyazo.com/91deb470a88b6066de9015beec5c0eed

I'd like for it to scale horizontally without showing upcoming frames of the animation.

Comment: If the aspect ratio isn't the issue, what is? Do you just need to know what to use instead of pixels?

Comment: Hi @BSMP! I'm not sure how to scale it at all to be honest, I'm very new to both HTML and CSS. When I try scaling the div it ends up repeating horizontally as the background width doesn't scale independently. I hope that clarified it a bit!

Comment: Can you explain what the desired behaviour is, and maybe provide enough of your code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: EDIT: Updated JS Fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/JaredMerritt/j7L4amov/

Comment: That still doesn't explain how you _want_ it to behave ... if preserving aspect ratio is _not_ the issue - then where's the problem with just using 100vw/vh for width and height, instead of very specific pixel values?

Comment: I've attached a gyazo to demonstrate my issue @Cbroe

Comment: Ah, I think now I get it ... using `background-size: auto 100%` instead of `cover` would be a start - stretch it to the height only. But that doesn't play nice with the centering, and also cuts it of when the viewport is too narrow.  I think you might need to approach this in two ways. Put the frames in the image _above_ each other - that will help with horizontal centering. Now you will have to do the scaling and animation part with percentages - relating the actual pixel height of the image to the viewport height and number of frames. [...]

Comment: [...] And do the same thing, the other way around - including a different image with frames centered on the other axis, put next to each other - depending on whether the orientation is landscape or portrait. Other than that, I think you can only use JavaScript to calculate appropriate scaling factor and positioning dynamically.

Comment: Or maybe that is just me thinking way too complicated here ... maybe making sure the element always stays quadratic (width and height 100vmin) would be enough already? Centering that in the viewport would be possible in a multitude of ways, and then you just place a screen-filling solid black background behind it.

Comment: Something like this maybe ...? https://jsfiddle.net/j7L4amov/6/

Comment: Hey @CBroe, thanks a lot for your help so far! Its essentially a page load animation, so it needs to stretch across both horizontally and vertically. Is there a way I could scale the CSS to fit the viewport? The input frame never changes size, so couldn't I just scale it or something? Thanks again, I think you're seeing why this is so irritating haha!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your biggest issue is that your image needs an aspect ratio that it is not. You can set its own aspect ratio by embedding it into another div and following something like [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp)

I managed to make something that maintains the aspect ratio, but it isn't vertically centered when the height is smaller than the aspect ratio.

```css
@keyframes play {
  100% {
    background-position: center left;
  }
}

body,
html {
  /* To be fair, these should always be disabled to prevent unexpected padding or margin or movements*/
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
}

.center.y {
  top: 0; bottom: 0; /* vertical center */
}

.center.x {
  left: 0; right: 0; /* horizontal center */
  margin: auto;
}

.lock.height {
  max-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
}

.lock.width {
  max-width: 100vw;
  width: 100vw;
}

.flow-background-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.flow-background {
  padding-top: 56.338%;
  /* For the 400/710 aspect ratio*/
  background: url('https://www.contingentgame.com/storage/themes/godlike/assets/images/preloader-bg.png') no-repeat center right;
  /* several types for more support. IE9+ http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts */
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: play 1.5s steps(22) infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="flow-background-container lock height">
  <div class="flow-background center x y">
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know the layout of your page so I can't center the div for you vertically. **How I did it**

```
.center-vertically {
position: relative;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-khtml-transform: translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
-o-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Originally I misunderstood what you were trying to do. playing with this I found that you must scale it so the height is the largest dimension so it doesn't repeat horizontally. to add to the illusion I made the background black and centered it, also I reversed the order so it looked more explosiony to me.

you can also see it on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j7L4amov/11/

```css
html, body{ 
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
 }
 
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 710px;
  width:  calc( 100vh * 16.0 / 9.0 );
}

.pageOpen {
  min-height: 400px;
  min-width: 710px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 background: url('https://www.contingentgame.com/storage/themes/godlike/assets/images/preloader-bg.png') no-repeat right center;
 background-size: cover;
 animation: play 1.5s steps(22) infinite;
 overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes play {
    100% {
      background-position: left center; 
    }
}
```

```html
<div class=wrapper>
<div class=pageOpen>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. If you see in my JS Fiddle, I need it to completely fill the box https://jsfiddle.net/JaredMerritt/j7L4amov/